# Communicating back to an Akka actor from an object declared inside of it

Tags: java, akka, listener

Java (well, Groovy, but that shouldn't matter) & Akka here (Maven/Gradle coordinates `'com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:2.4.4'`), **using Akka's Java API**.

I have a situation where I need to have an actor listen for certain events:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class Watchdog implements UntypedActor {
    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StartListening) {
            // Start listening for events occuring *outside* the actor system.
        }
    }
}
```

However I have multiple implementations of *how* this `Watchdog` needs to listen for events. One implementation listens for keyboard/`STDIN` inputs via Java's `Scanner`. Another implementation might listen for data coming in over a TCP, UDP or serial port. So I have abstracted the actual listening out into an interface:

```
interface WatchdogListener {
    void startListening(ActorRef watchdog)
}
```

So now my actor looks like:

```
class Watchdog implements UntypedActor {
    WatchdogListener watchdogListener

    @Override
    void onReceive(Object message) {
        if(message instanceof StartListening) {
            watchdogListener = new ScannerWatchdogListener()
            // or
            // watchdogListener = new SerialPortWatchdogListener()

            watchdogListener.startListening(this)
        } else if(message instanceof InputEvent) {
            // Handle the input event, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Because I've made this abstraction, I need the `WatchdogListener` impl to be able to communicate back to the `Watchdog` actor when an "event" occurs:

```
class ScannerWatchdogListener implements WatchdogListener {
    void startListening(ActorRef watchdog) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
        while(true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine()
            watchdog.tell(new InputEvent(input), ActorRef.noSender())
        }
    }
}
```

Similar for the `SerialPortWatchdogListener` impl.

The problem is that `Watchdog` is of type `UntypedActor`, *not* `ActorRef`. If I change `WatchdogListener` to:

```
interface WatchdogListener {
    void startListening(UntypedActor watchdog)
}
```

Then I lose the ability to call `tell(...)` from inside of the `WatchdogListener` impl.

**What are my options here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing in `this` when calling `startListening` inside of your actor, pass in `self()`.  Using `self()` will pass in an `ActorRef` and then you can `tell` back to it in your listener.

Comment: Awesome @cmbaxter (+1) - thank you! Any chance I could get you to confirm I'm not violating any Akka best practices here, or implementing any Akka anti-patterns? Thanks again!

Comment: Passing around an `ActorRef` is just fine.  You may also consider implementing the listeners themselves as Actors and then setting them up to be child actors of the `Watchdog` and then just use the built in parent reference to send back to instead of passing one in.

Comment: I aggre with @cmbaxter maybe an ListenerActor could be more fine.